# Cosmos DB container cannot be updated when DB has "Continuous" backup policy

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Some time ago I enabled `"backupPolicy": { "type": "Continuous" }` on one of my Cosmos DB accounts.

Now, when I try to update an existing Cosmos *container* via ARM, [Az Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.cosmosdb/update-azcosmosdbsqlcontainer?view=azps-6.0.0), Az CLI, or even directly via Azure [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db-resource-provider/2021-04-15/sql-resources/create-update-sql-container), I get the *One of the specified inputs is invalid* error:

> {
> "status": "Failed",
> "error": {
> "code": "BadRequest",
> "message": "Message: {"code":"BadRequest","message":"Message:
> {\"Errors\":[\"One of the specified inputs is
> invalid\"]}\r\nActivityId: 707c2fe1-42cd-43aa-b050-5ec8d85a0e06,
> Request URI:
> /apps/0f4ef045-e4bc-485d-b639-54cf7639406a/services/c28010c2-ddff-4fe3-b0ac-d1e11b612c12/partitions/741b17db-ca07-4833-8cca-5314763179d8/replicas/132677385232196284p,
> RequestStats: \r\nRequestStartTime: 2021-06-16T07:30:02.8308239Z,
> RequestEndTime: 2021-06-16T07:30:02.8308239Z,  Number of regions
> attempted:1\r\nResponseTime: 2021-06-16T07:30:02.8308239Z,
> StoreResult: StorePhysicalAddress:
> rntbd://10.0.0.24:11000/apps/0f4ef045-e4bc-485d-b639-54cf7639406a/services/c28010c2-ddff-4fe3-b0ac-d1e11b612c12/partitions/741b17db-ca07-4833-8cca-5314763179d8/replicas/132677385232196284p,
> LSN: 14, GlobalCommittedLsn: 14, PartitionKeyRangeId: , IsValid: True,
> StatusCode: 400, SubStatusCode: 0, RequestCharge: 1.24, ItemLSN: -1,
> SessionToken: -1#14, UsingLocalLSN: False, TransportException: null,
> BELatencyMs: 1.9, ActivityId: 707c2fe1-42cd-43aa-b050-5ec8d85a0e06,
> ResourceType: Collection, OperationType: Replace\r\n, SDK:
> Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0"}, Request URI:
> /dbs/ht-app/colls/test, RequestStats: , SDK:
> Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0,
> Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0,
> Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0,
> Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0,
> Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0"
> } }

What I tested:

1. The same ARM templates and PS/Az CLI/REST API command inputs work on another account that has `"type": "Periodic"` backup policy.
2. The same ARM template works the first time when the container doesn't exist yet.
3. The same ARM template worked before but stopped working on ~10th of June.

I still can apply changes via the Portal but all programmatic ways of doing that are failing.

**UPDATE**

Here is how I create the container:

```
PS /home/user> az cosmosdb sql container create `
>> --account-name "redacted" `
>> --database-name "redacted" `
>> --name "test2" `
>> --resource-group "redacted" `
>> --partition-key-path "/mykey"
{
  "id": "/subscriptions/<redacted>/resourceGroups/redacted/providers/Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/redacted/sqlDatabases/redacted/containers/test2",
  "location": null,
  "name": "test2",
  "options": null,
  "resource": {
    "_conflicts": "conflicts/",
    "_docs": "docs/",
    "_self": "dbs/-EA0AA==/colls/-EA0AOFM4Qc=/",
    "_sprocs": "sprocs/",
    "_triggers": "triggers/",
    "_udfs": "udfs/",
    "allowMaterializedViews": false,
    "analyticalStorageTtl": null,
    "backupPolicy": {
      "type": 1
    },
    "conflictResolutionPolicy": {
      "conflictResolutionPath": "/_ts",
      "conflictResolutionProcedure": "",
      "mode": "LastWriterWins"
    },
    "defaultTtl": null,
    "etag": "\"0000cf0c-0000-0d00-0000-60c9c85e0000\"",
    "geospatialConfig": {
      "type": "Geography"
    },
    "id": "test2",
    "indexingPolicy": {
      "automatic": true,
      "compositeIndexes": null,
      "excludedPaths": [
        {
          "path": "/\"_etag\"/?"
        }
      ],
      "includedPaths": [
        {
          "indexes": null,
          "path": "/*"
        }
      ],
      "indexingMode": "consistent",
      "spatialIndexes": null
    },
    "partitionKey": {
      "kind": "Hash",
      "paths": [
        "/mykey"
      ],
      "systemKey": null,
      "version": null
    },
    "rid": "-EA0AOFM4Qc=",
    "statistics": [
      {
        "documentCount": 0,
        "id": "0",
        "partitionKeys": [],
        "sizeInKB": 0
      }
    ],
    "ts": 1623836766.0,
    "uniqueKeyPolicy": {
      "uniqueKeys": []
    }
  },
  "resourceGroup": "redacted",
  "tags": null,
  "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/containers"
}
```

This is the update (with no actual changes) that fails:

```
PS /home/user> az cosmosdb sql container update `
>> --account-name "redacted" `
>> --database-name "redacted" `
>> --name "test2" `
>> --resource-group "redacted"
(BadRequest) Message: {"code":"BadRequest","message":"Message: {\"Errors\":[\"One of the specified inputs is invalid\"]}\r\nActivityId: fb640be2-ce87-11eb-8bf9-0a580af44a33, Request URI: /apps/0f4ef045-e4bc-485d-b639-54cf7639406a/services/c28010c2-ddff-4fe3-b0ac-d1e11b612c12/partitions/741b17db-ca07-4833-8cca-5314763179d8/replicas/132677385232196284p, RequestStats: \r\nRequestStartTime: 2021-06-16T09:48:24.7589460Z, RequestEndTime: 2021-06-16T09:48:24.7688873Z,  Number of regions attempted:1\r\nResponseTime: 2021-06-16T09:48:24.7688873Z, StoreResult: StorePhysicalAddress: rntbd://10.0.0.24:11000/apps/0f4ef045-e4bc-485d-b639-54cf7639406a/services/c28010c2-ddff-4fe3-b0ac-d1e11b612c12/partitions/741b17db-ca07-4833-8cca-5314763179d8/replicas/132677385232196284p, LSN: 16, GlobalCommittedLsn: 16, PartitionKeyRangeId: , IsValid: True, StatusCode: 400, SubStatusCode: 0, RequestCharge: 1.24, ItemLSN: -1, SessionToken: -1#16, UsingLocalLSN: False, TransportException: null, BELatencyMs: 1.675, ActivityId: fb640be2-ce87-11eb-8bf9-0a580af44a33, ResourceType: Collection, OperationType: Replace\r\n, SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0"}, Request URI: /dbs/redacted/colls/test2, RequestStats: , SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include what updates are you applying on the container.

Comment: I've got the same issue.  Deploys were fine, but just suddenly started getting this. Nothing has changed in my container definition.   Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @oatsoda No, because of this problem I had to abandon the ARM templates. Now I create containers via PowerShell, only if they don't exist.

Comment: @Monsignor Thanks, useful to know. I've tried to raise it with MS but not heard anything yet. It appears new containers are still created even though there are errors. I guess I'll have to go down a non-ARM route for this too, for now.

Comment: @Monsignor Mine seems to have started working again now...

Comment: @oatsoda Thanks for the info, it seems to be working on my end as well. I presume the underlying bug was fixed by the Azure devs. Have they resolved your support request?

Comment: @Monsignor I never got around to submitting one :D  Like you say, seems like they pushed a fix for whatever they had broken.  I guess continuous backup is still in preview.